# How to open file .txt with using openFileDialog in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to open and read from a `.txt` file, here is the code I'm using:

```
Stream myStream;
openFileDialog1.FileName = string.Empty; 
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "F:\\";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    var compareType = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    if (extension.Equals(".txt", compareType))
    {
        try 
        { 
            using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) 
            { 
                string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                string path = Path.GetFullPath(file); //when i did it like this it's work fine but all the time give me same path whatever where my "*.txt" file is
                //Insert code to read the stream here. 
                //fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName; 
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
                MessageBox.Show(file, "fileName");
                MessageBox.Show(path, "Directory");
            } 
        } 
        // Exception thrown: Empty path name is not legal
        catch (ArgumentException ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. " +
                            "Original error: " + ex.Message); 
        } 
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invaild File Type Selected");
    } 
}
```

The code above throws an exception which says *"Empty path name is not legal"*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how to read 2 matrix from txt file using openFileDialog

Comment: It depends on how they are stored there. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Harry - in your code you have a comment saying "`//i've got exception for now:(`" is this what the problem is? Can you copy and paste the exception. People are trying to help here but you're not helping us. Please be more specific as to what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Kev it's what exception says "Empty path name is not legal"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed by [hmemcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8205/hmemcpy), your problem is in the following lines

```
using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
   string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
   string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
   MessageBox.Show(file, "fileName");
   MessageBox.Show(path, "Directory");
}
```

I'm going to break down for you:

```
/*
 * Opend the file selected by the user (for instance, 'C:\user\someFile.txt'), 
 * creating a FileStream
 */
using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
   /*
    * Gets the name of the the selected by the user: 'someFile.txt'
    */
   string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

   /*
    * Gets the path of the above file: ''
    *
    * That's because the above line gets the name of the file without any path.
    * If there is no path, there is nothing for the line below to return
    */
   string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);

   /*
    * Try to open a reader for the above bar: Exception!
    */
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);

   MessageBox.Show(file, "fileName");
   MessageBox.Show(path, "Directory");
}
```

What you should do is to cahnge the code to something like

```
using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
{
   // ...
   var reader = new StreamReader(myStream);
   // ...
}
```

Comment: i changed that what u write and now i got no path only white space in 2nd Messagebox. Any idea why?

Comment: change the line `string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file)` to `string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName)`

Answer (score 6):

You want user to select only .txt files?
Then use the [.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx) property, like that:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Comment: i did it in properties of openFiledialog control

Comment: Then that's your problem? How to create an instance of the class?

Answer (score 5):

Your bug is in the lines:

```
string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
```

In the first line the `file` variable will only contain the file name, e.g. `MyFile.txt`, making the second line return an empty string to the `path` variable. Further down your code you'll attempt to create a `StreamReader` with an empty path, and this what throws the exception.

By the way, this is exactly what the exception tells you. If you remove the `try..catch` around the using block, you would've seen it happen during debug in your Visual Studio.

Comment: oh ok :) then how get all path of this file?

Comment: You already have the path of the file in `openFileDialog1.FileName`

Answer (score 2):

StreamReader accepts Stream type of object while you are passing it a string.
try this,

```
Stream myStream;

        using (myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())
        {
            string file = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string file2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myStream);

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadLine());
            }

            MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(file, "fileName");
            MessageBox.Show(path, "Directory");
        }
```